# Find $P \left( X + Y + Z + U \ge 1 \right)$

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

Find $P \left( X + Y + Z + U \ge 1 \right)$ if the joint probability density function is
$
f \left(x, y, z, u \right) = 
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{24}{(1 + x + y + z + u)^5} & x > 0, y > 0, z > 0, u > 0 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
  \right.
$.

Comment: Could you please add a self-study tag and read through https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2419794/321264.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step:

Calculate $P \left( X \ge 1 \right)$ if the pdf is
$
  f \left( x \right) =
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{1}{\left( 1 + x \right)^2} & x > 0 \\
        0 & x \le 0
      \end{array}
    \right.
$

Second step:

Calculate $P \left( X + Y \ge 1 \right)$ if the joint pdf is
$
  f \left( x, y \right) =
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{2}{\left( 1 + x + y \right)^3} & x > 0, y > 0 \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
      \end{array}
    \right.
$

Third step:

Calculate $P \left( X + Y +Z \ge 1 \right)$ if the joint pdf is
$
  f \left( x, y, z\right) =
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{6}{\left( 1 + x + y + z \right)^4} & x > 0, y > 0, z >0 \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
      \end{array}
    \right.
$

Fourth step:

your question.

Comment: Could you indicate how your exponential $f$ (which isn't even a valid pdf) is relevant to the $f$ of the question?

Comment: I was just wanted to start with a probability calculated from a pdf first with one variable (it supposed to be valid, just there was a typo, corrected).

Comment: This exponential distribution is easy to do. But how it helps the asked question? Please explain. Thank you

Comment: Reeba, By not explaining what steps you have taken you are making us guess what kind of help you need.  It looks like oszkar may have guessed incorrectly--but we cannot reasonably expect him to read your mind.  Please edit your question to show us where you're stuck.

Comment: I am totally confused how to proceed it. First part of this question was to find $P(X>Y>Z>U)$. It was solved by substituting for u+1 in the first step of integration, then z+1 in the second step, and so on. But here i tried transformation for X+Y+Z+U, X+Y+Z, X+Y and X. But it didn't work. Also I dont know what substitution is to done. Please help.

Comment: @reebamary Please add these thoughts in your post, not in comments.

Comment: @reebamary Check my suggested steps, I have modified the first one, I hope now they will show you the way.

Comment: @StubbornAtom  I'm really sorry. I'm new here. Now only I got an idea.

Comment: @oszkar Thank you very much. Starting from the univariate case, it seems to be very easy. Thank you for your help.